# jqGrid row height increase when save it

Tags: jqgrid-asp.net

I am new to jqGrid. I'm using a grid with datatype as function. When I edit a row, its height is increased so that the controls fit. If I restore the row height is reset, but if I save the data do not, so when I go back to edit, the row height increases again.

Comment: "but if I save the data do not, so when I go back to edit, the row height increases again." You should write that again, since it's a bit hard to understand  what you mean.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry. I'm from Spain, and I don't speak English. This sentence, in particular, is a translation from Google. I do that I can :(

Comment: no worries, tell me in Spanish and I´ll give you the translation!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific example in front of me at the moment, but I have used jqGrid extensively and found that between using the height parameter and some custom CSS I've been able to fix problems that sound similar to yours.

For example,

```
jQuery("#examplegrid").jqGrid({
    url:'/your/jsonapiurl',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['ID','First Column', 'Second Column'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:55},
        {name:'firstcolumn',index:'firstcolumn', width:90},
        {name:'secondcolumn',index:'secondcolumn', width:100}       
    ],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#examplepager',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    width: 500,
    height: "100%",
    caption: "Example"
});
```

Note the height parameter - I'm guessing you've already tried chaing the height parameter from 100% to something appropriate, but if the height is still misbehaving, you can try CSS like so:

```
#examplegrid .jqgrow {
    height: 25px;
    max-height: 25px;
}
```

And you may want to make that specific to the type of controls that you have in your rows by modifying the css selector or just generalize it, remove the id to hit all grids on the same page if you have more than one grid on a page, etc.

If you've already tried those things and for some reason CSS isn't working to keep the row height correct, I'd take a look at the order of the CSS.  Pop it open in Chrome say for example and take a look at whether or not your CSS for height is being overridden someplace.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, hoonto. I specified max-height in css, and this dont' work. I'll keep trying other things.
As someone said earlier, I can not explain in English, so do not bother you anymore. Thanks, hoonto :)

Comment: Well, finally I used "aftersavefunc" and "afterrestorefunc" for reload grid after save or restore in jQuery(this).jqGrid('editRow', id,.... ) , and "aftersavefunc" for reload grid after save in jQuery(this).jqGrid('saveRow'.....)
Thank you.

Comment: Good call, I completely forgot about that!  I'm happy to hear it worked out. Rgds....Matt